# OpenCL headers missing from the OpenCL framework in OS X Mavericks?

Tags: macos, opencl, osx-mavericks

I'm trying to compile cpyrit_opencl in Mac and I'm getting this error:

```
_cpyrit_opencl.c:40:10 fatal error: 'cl.h' file not found
     #include <cl.h>
              ^
```

I navigated to the /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework directory, and behold, there is no "Headers" folder in there.

I am currently running OS X 10.9.2 (Build 13C64), and have also tried with 10.9.1.

To see if this is an error specific to the python script that used to build cpyrit_opencl, I ran:

```
clang -framework OpenCL -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 _cpyrit_opencl.c
```

to compile the file manually, this also produced the exact same error as above.

I tried googling to see if anyone else wrote about no OpenCL headers, and found nothing relating to Mac.

Also, I checked and the headers were missing on both of my Macs, both running 10.9.2.

Comment: Strange. I'm running 10.9.2 and there is a `Headers` directory under `/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework`.

Comment: Isn't it usually #include <CL/cl.h>?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On macs, I find that I always need to use the framework name when including a framework header. Thus,

```
#include <OpenCL/OpenCL.h>
or
#include <OpenCL/cl.h>
```

I can't seem to find it at the moment either, though.
You still always need the "-framework OpenCL" option you've already got, too.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the include that is defined in _cpyrit_opencl.c if it being built using Mac, and changed it to #include <OpenCL/OpenCL.h> and it successfully built!